# Remove White Background of Transparent Image

Tags: html

I'm currently working on launching my webstore from a template. As I upload my custom PNG images with transparent background, on the home page it still shows the image with a white background around it.

I've tried altering it using CCS and HTML however was unable to.

Here you can see the problem:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbIkY.png)

[Transparent Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzICF.png)

And here it is the code (CSS):

```
--------------------------------------------- */
body {
  color: {{theme.primary_color}};
  font-family: "{{theme.text_font}}", sans-serif;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  cursor: default;
}

input,
textarea {
  color: {{theme.primary_color}};
  font-family: "{{theme.text_font}}", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

a {
  color: {{theme.primary_color}};
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: {{theme.primary_color}};
}

p,
.main ul,
.main ol,
.main table,
label {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.main p a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.main p a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background: {{theme.highlight_color}};
}

h1, h2, h3 {
  font-family: "{{theme.header_font}}", sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

h4 {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.09em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.highlight {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: {{theme.primary_color}};
  background: {{theme.highlight_color}};
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

ul.bullets {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 22px;
  margin-left: 18px;
}

ul.bullets li {
  list-style: disc;
}

/* GLOBAL LAYOUT
--------------------------------------------- */
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: {{theme.background_color}};
  background-image: {% if theme.images.background != blank %} url("{{ theme.images.background.url }}") {% else %} none {% endif %};
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -80px;
}

.wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  /* equal to footer height */
  height: 80px;
}

.inner {
  max-width: 1200px;
  min-width: 280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.main .inner {
  margin-top: 130px;
}

/* MODULES
--------------------------------------------- */
/* Buttons */
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  font-family: "{{theme.text_font}}", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: {{theme.primary_color}};
  border: 3px solid {{theme.primary_color}};
  background: none;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: {{theme.primary_color}};
  color: {{theme.background_color}};
}

.btn-inactive:hover {
  background: none;
  color: {{theme.primary_color}};
}

/* Badges */
.badge {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 70px;
  display: table;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.badge span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.badge-empty {
  color: {{theme.primary_color}};
  border: 3px solid {{theme.primary_color}};
}

.badge-filled {
  color: {{theme.primary_color}};
  background: {{theme.background_color}};
  border: 3px solid {{theme.background_color}};
}

/* Errors */
.errors {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background: {{theme.highlight_color}};
}

.errors li {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.errors li:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

/* Pagers */
.cycle-pager {
  position: absolute;
  left: 24px;
  bottom: 24px;
  z-index: 400;
}

.cycle-pager > span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  padding: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cycle-pager > span > span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  background: {{theme.highlight_color}};
  border: 3px solid {{theme.primary_color}};
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: background 300ms;
  -moz-transition: background 300ms;
  -o-transition: background 300ms;
  transition: background 300ms;
}

.cycle-pager span.cycle-pager-active span {
  background: {{theme.primary_color}};
  -webkit-transition: background 300ms;
  -moz-transition: background 300ms;
  -o-transition: background 300ms;
  transition: background 300ms;
}

/* HEADER
--------------------------------------------- */
header {
  background: {{theme.background_color}};
  border-bottom: 6px solid {{theme.primary_color}};
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 501;
}

.maintenance_on header {
  top: 27px;
}

header .inner {
  height: 70px;
  position: relative;
}

.wordmark {
  float: left;
  font-family: "{{theme.header_font}}", sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-top: 24px;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 70px;
  width: 300px;
  background-image: {% if theme.images.logo != blank %} url("{{ theme.images.logo.url | constrain: '600', '140' }}") {% else %} none {% endif %};
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.logo img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.nav-main {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 70px;
  z-index: 500;
}

.nav-main a,
.nav-main > ul > li > span {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: {{theme.primary_color}};
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.09em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.nav-main > ul {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  height: 70px;
}

.nav-main > ul > li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-main > ul > li > a,
.nav-main > ul > li > span {
  display: block;
  height: 12px;
  padding: 29px 25px;
}

.nav-main > ul > li.active > a,
.nav-main > ul > li.active > span {
  background: {{theme.primary_color}};
  color: {{theme.background_color}};
}

.nav-main .dropdown {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  padding: 6px 0 0 0;
  right: 0px;
  background: {{theme.primary_color}};
  text-align: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.nav-main > ul > li.active .dropdown {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.icon-cart {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.nav-main .dropdown li {
  display: block;
  line-height: 18px;
}

.nav-main .dropdown li a {
  display: block;
  color: {{theme.background_color}};
  padding: 15px 20px;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.nav-main .dropdown li a:hover {
  color: {{theme.background_color}};
  background: {{theme.highlight_color}};
  color: {{theme.primary_color}};
}

.nav-caret {
  text-transform: lowercase;
  font-size: 7px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: -2px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.5);
  -moz-transform: scaleX(1.5);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(1.5);
  -o-transform: scaleX(1.5);
  transform: scaleX(1.5);
}

.mobile-nav-trigger {
  display: none;
}

.cart-status {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes orbpulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }

  25% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }

  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes orbpulse {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }

  25% {
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
  }

  50% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }

  75% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  }

  100% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes orbpulse {
  0% {
    -o-transform: scale(1);
  }

  25% {
    -o-transform: scale(2);
  }

  50% {
    -o-transform: scale(1);
  }

  75% {
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
  }

  100% {
    -o-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes orbpulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  25% {
    transform: scale(2);
  }

  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  75% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.cart-orb {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 80px;
  background: {{theme.highlight_color}};
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 505;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 100ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 100ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 100ms ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 100ms ease-in-out;
}

.cart-status .cart-orb {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0, 0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0, 0);
  -o-transform: scale(0, 0);
  transform: scale(0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 100ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 100ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 100ms ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 100ms ease-in-out;
}

.cart-status:hover .cart-orb {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.6, 1.6);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.6, 1.6);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.6, 1.6);
  -o-transform: scale(1.6, 1.6);
  transform: scale(1.6, 1.6);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 100ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 100ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 100ms ease-out;
  transition: transform 100ms ease-out;
}

/* Disable orb on cart pages */
.cart .cart-status:hover .cart-orb {
  display: none;
}

.cart-count {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 510;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms;
  -o-transition: all 100ms;
  transition: all 100ms;
}

.icon-cart {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
  z-index: 510;
}

.cart-status .cart-count-animate {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 16px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, 16px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 16px);
  -o-transform: translate(0, 16px);
  transform: translate(0, 16px);
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms;
  -o-transition: all 100ms;
  transition: all 100ms;
}

.cart-status .cart-orb-animate {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.6, 1.6);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.6, 1.6);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.6, 1.6);
  -o-transform: scale(1.6, 1.6);
  transform: scale(1.6, 1.6);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 150ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 150ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 150ms ease-out;
  transition: transform 150ms ease-out;
}

.nav-mobile {
  display: none;
}

}

.color-block-products {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: {{theme.accent_color}};
  background-image: {% if theme.images.accent != blank %} url("{{ theme.images.accent.url }}") {% else %} none {% endif %};
}

.preview {
  width: 300px;
}

.rand-0 {
  width: 330px;
  top: 40px;
}

.rand-0 .badge-view {
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

.rand-0 .badge-status {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.rand-1 {
  width: 280px;
  top: 20px;
}

.rand-1 .badge-view {
  top: 21%;
  right: -20px;
}

.rand-1 .badge-status {
  bottom: 20%;
  left: -20px;
}

.rand-2 {
  width: 350px;
  top: 0px;
}

.rand-2 .badge-view {
  top: 30%;
  right: 20px;
}

.rand-2 .badge-status {
  top: 8%;
  left: 20px;
}

.rand-3 {
  width: 320px;
  top: 40px;
}

.rand-3 .badge-view {
  bottom: 20%;
  left: -20px;
}

.rand-3 .badge-status {
  top: 10%;
  right: -20px;
}

.rand-4 {
  width: 400px;
  top: -20px;
}

.rand-4 .badge-view {
  top: 20%;
  left: -20px;
}

.rand-4 .badge-status {
  bottom: 15%;
  right: 20px;
}

.rand-5 {
  top: 20px;
}

.rand-5 .badge-view {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.rand-5 .badge-status {
  top: -20px;
  right: -20px;
}

.rand-6 {
  width: 330px;
  top: 0px;
}

.rand-6 .badge-view {
  top: -20px;
  right: 20px;
}

.rand-6 .badge-status {
  bottom: 10%;
  left: -20px;
}

.home-slideshow-wrap {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 76px auto 0;
  position: relative;
}

.home-slideshow {
  margin-left: 80px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.slideshow-stripe {
  width: 80px;
  height: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: {{theme.highlight_color}};
}

/* Categories / Artists */
.products .main .inner {
  margin-top: 130px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* EXTRA LARGE */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
  .home-slideshow-wrap {
    max-width: 1480px;
  }
}
/* LARGE */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1245px) {
  .preview {
    margin: 0 15px 70px 15px;
  }

  .preview {
    width: 200px;
  }

  .meta {
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .meta .price {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 -5px 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
  }

  .rand-0 {
    width: 240px;
    top: 40px;
  }

  .rand-1 {
    width: 200px;
    top: 20px;
  }

  .rand-2 {
    width: 250px;
    top: 0px;
  }

  .rand-3 {
    width: 220px;
    top: 40px;
  }

  .rand-4 {
    width: 300px;
    top: -20px;
  }

  .rand-5 {
    top: 20px;
  }

  .rand-6 {
    width: 230px;
    top: 0px;
  }

  .pagination {
    font-size: 32px;
  }
}
/* MEDIUM */
@media only screen and (max-width: 880px) {
  /* Home */
  .home-slideshow-wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .home-slideshow {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  .slideshow-stripe {
    display: none;
  }

  /* Categories / Artists */
  .products .main .inner {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
}
/* SMALL */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .preview {
    margin: 0 15px 20px 15px;
  }

  .rand-0 {
    width: 210px;
    top: 0;
  }

  .rand-1 {
    width: 200px;
    top: 0;
  }

  .rand-2 {
    width: 230px;
    top: 0;
  }

  .rand-3 {
    width: 210px;
    top: 0;
  }

  .rand-4 {
    width: 190px;
    top: 0;
  }

  .rand-5 {
    width: 210px;
    top: 0;
  }

  .rand-6 {
    width: 230px;
    top: 0;
  }

  .pagination {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
  }

  /* Categories / Artists */
  .products .main .inner {
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
/* EXTRA SMALL */
@media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {
  /* Products */
  .preview {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  }

  .rand-0 {
    width: 260px;
    top: 0;
  }

  .rand-1 {
    width: 250px;
    top: 0;
  }

  .rand-2 {
    width: 280px;
    top: 0;
  }

  .rand-3 {
    width: 260px;
    top: 0;
  }

  .rand-4 {
    width: 210px;
    top: 0;
  }

  .rand-5 {
    width: 280px;
    top: 0;
  }

  .rand-6 {
    width: 240px;
    top: 0;
  }

  .pagination {
    padding: 0 40px;
  }
}
.product .main .inner {
  margin-top: 76px;
}

.product .wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.product .images {
  float: right;
  width: 66%;
  background-color: {{theme.accent_color}};
  background-image: {% if theme.images.accent != blank %} url("{{ theme.images.accent.url }}") {% else %} none {% endif %};
}

.product .images-inner {
  position: relative;
}

.product .color-block {
  width: 2000%;
  height: 2000%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: {{theme.accent_color}};
  background-image: {% if theme.images.accent != blank %} url("{{ theme.images.accent.url }}") {% else %} none {% endif %};
  z-index: -1;
}

.slideshow {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: {{theme.accent_color}};
  background-image: {% if theme.images.accent != blank %} url("{{ theme.images.accent.url }}") {% else %} none {% endif %};
}

.slideshow img {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.product .details {
  float: left;
  width: 28%;
}

.product h2 {
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}

.product h4 {
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

.product .description {
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}

.product .errors {
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}

.product .description b,
.product .description strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.product .description i,
.product .description em {
  font-style: italic;
}

.static-option-list {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.product .description p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.product .description p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.badge-sale {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  z-index: 400;
}

.product .price {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.purchase {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.social-links {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.social-links li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.social-links li a {
  display: block;
  background: {{theme.primary_color}};
  color: {{theme.background_color}};
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 0.09em;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.social-links li a:hover {
  color: {{theme.highlight_color}};
}

@-webkit-keyframes purchasepulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes purchasepulse {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.95);
  }

  50% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  }

  100% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes purchasepulse {
  0% {
    -o-transform: scale(0.95);
  }

  50% {
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
  }

  100% {
    -o-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes purchasepulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
  }

  50% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.btn-purchase {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 100ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 100ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 100ms ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 100ms ease-in-out;
}

.btn-active:active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.95, 0.95);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.95, 0.95);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.95, 0.95);
  -o-transform: scale(0.95, 0.95);
  transform: scale(0.95, 0.95);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 50ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 50ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 50ms ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 50ms ease-in-out;
}

.btn-pulse {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  -o-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 100ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 100ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 100ms ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 100ms ease-in-out;
}

.btn-inactive:hover {
  background: none;
  color: {{theme.primary_color}};
  cursor: default;
}

.options {
  border: 3px solid {{theme.primary_color}};
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.option-selected {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 22px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.option-selected:hover {
  color: {{theme.background_color}};
  background: {{theme.primary_color}};
}

.option-selected-name {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.options-wrap {
  height: 48px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.options-list {
  background: {{theme.background_color}};
  height: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.options-list li {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.options-list li:hover {
  background: {{theme.primary_color}};
  color: {{theme.background_color}};
}

.options .dropdown-caret {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  margin-top: -12px;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  font-size: 7px;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 700;
  -moz-transform: scalex(1.5);
  -ms-transform: scalex(1.5);
  -o-transform: scalex(1.5);
  -webkit-transform: scalex(1.5);
  transform: scalex(1.5);
}

/* LARGE */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1245px) {
  .product .main .inner {
    margin-right: 0;
  }

  .product h2 {
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
}
/* MEDIUM */
@media only screen and (max-width: 880px) {
  .product .main .inner {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
/* SMALL */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .product .details,
  .product .images {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
  }

  .product .images {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .product .images-inner {
    display: block;
  }

  .product .details {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 20px;
  }

  .product .description,
  .product .bullets {
    text-align: left;
  }

  .product .color-block {
    display: none;
  }

  .product .main .inner {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .badge-sale {
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
  }
```

Comment: You should use PNG image formate

Comment: you need to use `.png` files that have a transparent background - not pos with html/css that I'm aware of

Comment: The first image is a PNG with transparent background; however still shows up with the white background

Comment: @Joshua show related css - it's not a HTML issue if that's the case

Comment: If your .png actually has transparent pixels, then check to see where something in your CSS is setting the white background.  If your .png has white background pixels, then there's nothing you can do in CSS to make those transparent.

Comment: Please see CSS in the updated post.

Comment: Thank you all for your help (I don't know where to even start)

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle so we can, well.. Fiddle with it?

Comment: upload an example of your png here (like you did with the problem image) so we can see if it has transparency.  Also check your server is set to serve pngs - some servers need that format adding

Comment: Check the post - I uploaded a transparent image.

Comment: ok this looks ok, can you show the html for the box that the image is ion - so we know what classes to look for in your code - you probably have something like this set: `background: {{theme.highlight_color}};` setting the background of your box to white

Answer (score 0):

This is a shopify related question. It is pretty hard to tell from the code provided but as i can see, you have a `class="image-wrap"` which sits around your image, that might be set to have a background of white.
You will have to check that in your css

Comment: you have a class of  .color-block-products. Try removing the backgroun-color property. If it doesent work, add back the background-color property and try doing the same for .product .images class

Comment: If this were the problem, would I simply remove it, or adjust the code?

Comment: you can use #000 instead of {{theme.accent_color}} and check if your background color has changed to black. If it did, remove the background-color property and your image should inherit the PNG background property (which we assume is transparent)